# Javascript Check variable.Then gain ++ per second

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem i want to check a variable.If its 0 then gain ++ after 1.5s.If its 10 then gain ++ after .4s.Its complicated.It doesnt really work.My code so far:

```
     if(road == 1){setInterval(function(){stamina = stamina+1;document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;},1400);}
else if(road == 2){setInterval(function(){stamina = stamina+1;document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;},1300);}
else if(road == 3){setInterval(function(){stamina = stamina+1;document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;},1200);}
else if(road == 4){setInterval(function(){stamina = stamina+1;document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;},1100);}
else if(road == 5){setInterval(function(){stamina = stamina+1;document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;},1000);}
else if(road == 6){setInterval(function(){stamina = stamina+1;document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;},900);}
else if(road == 7){setInterval(function(){stamina = stamina+1;document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;},800);}
else if(road == 8){setInterval(function(){stamina = stamina+1;document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;},600);}
else if(road == 9){setInterval(function(){stamina = stamina+1;document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;},400);}
else if(road == 10){setInterval(function(){stamina = stamina+1;document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;},200);}
else{setInterval(function(){stamina++;document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;},1500);}
```

And the code to build a road is this:

```
function build_road() {
    if ((wood + tavern) >= 29 && stone > 4 && road < 10) {
        road++;
        document.getElementById("road_count").innerHTML = road;
        wood = (wood + tavern) - 20;
        stone = stone - 5;
        document.getElementById("wood").innerHTML = wood;
        document.getElementById("stone").innerHTML = stone;
        exp = exp + 20;
        var x = document.getElementById("PROGRESS");
        x.setAttribute("value", exp);
        x.setAttribute("max", max);
        if (exp == 100) {
            exp = 0;
            level++;
            document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = level;
        }
        alert("Congratulations,You've create a Road,Now you gain stamina slightly faster.");
    }
    else {
        alert("You need: 30Wood,5Stone .Maximum 10 Roads.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Terrible code – instead of such if-elseif orgies, you should rather put timeout values into an array …

Comment: @CBroe Terrible comment - instead of giving such a pointless hint, you should rather write a quality answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make reusable functions (it's often a good practice, when you a difficulties with a piece of code, to break it into small functions):

   ```
   var staminaIncreaseTimer = null;

   function configureStaminaIncrease(delay) {
       if (staminaIncreaseTimer !== null)
           clearInterval(staminaIncreaseTimer);
       staminaIncreaseTimer = setInterval(function () {
           increaseStamina();
       }, delay);
   }

   function increaseStamina() {
       stamina += 1;
       document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;
   }
   ```
2. Solution with an array (suggested by Jay Harris)

   ```
   var roadIndex = road-1;
   var ROAD_DELAYS = [1400, 1300, 1200, /*...*/];
   var DEFAULT_DELAY = 1500;
   if (roadIndex < ROAD_DELAYS.length) {
       configureStaminaIncrease(ROAD_DELAYS[roadIndex]);
   } else {
       configureStaminaIncrease(DEFAULT_DELAY);
   }
   ```
3. Solution with a `switch` instead of you if-elseif mess:

   ```
   switch (road) {
       case 1:
           configureStaminaIncrease(1400);
           break;
       case 2:
           configureStaminaIncrease(1300);
           break;
       case 3:
           configureStaminaIncrease(1200);
           break;
       //and so on...
       default:
           configureStaminaIncrease(1500);
   }
   ```

Comment: smh you advised him to use a switch statement when the only thing that changes in each block is the time interval, your advice is essential equivalent to his code... why not just use an array ?

Comment: @jay-harris I was tired, thanks for the suggestion. Answer updated.

Comment: please and further instructions?im very new to  javascript programming.ok i guess i like the second solution.what should i do?note:i want the code to auto run and check always...because the road variable will get increased.Thanks for the help!